# Activate downloaded Magento Tempelate in Localhost (xamp server)

Tags: magento, xampp, localhost

i have downloaded theme in `Magento CMS` and now i want to `preview` this theme in `Localhost xampp server`. for that i have installed `magento` on `local server`.

but i dont know how to preview downloaded theme in `xampp` server.
**WHAT I HAVE DONE.** 
i have copied `app,js,media and skin` folder to the folder in `magento` installation directory but nothing made. please tell me how i can solve this..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

**View page source** to the admin page that you are looking for and view whether **setup.js** inside **js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tinymice/** is loaded or not. This js file loads your wysiwyg editor on admin page.

This normally occurs due to mismatch on code. So, you can copy core magento js folder from fresh magento installation and overwrite to your working site.

Try once !!